# Cycle2 fading Caption

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

Is there anyway to make some transition effects to [the caption in Cycle2](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/demo/caption.php)?

I want to make some effects to the caption such as `fadeIn` at each `cycle-update-view`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by hooking into jQuery cycle's before and after events:

```
$('.cycle-container').cycle();

$('.cycle-container').on('cycle-before', function(event, options, outgoing, incoming) {
    $(this).find(options.caption).fadeOut();
});

$('.cycle-container').on('cycle-after', function(event, options, outgoing, incoming) {
    $(this).find(options.caption).fadeIn();
});
```

It might be slightly more complicated to get it do a slide animation, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just hookup with [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/) then apply different transitions to different templates. Such as:

```
data-cycle-caption-template="<span class=caption1>{{caption1}}</span> <span class=caption2>{{caption2}}</span> <span class=caption3>{{caption3}}</span>"
```

Then on

```
<li 
   data-cycle-caption1="This is Slide 1 Caption 1" 
   data-cycle-caption2="This is Slide 1 Caption 2" 
   data-cycle-caption2="This is Slide 1 Caption 2" 
>
```

Some CSS

```
.cycle-caption {
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:20px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:20;
opacity:1;
}


.caption1 {
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFF;
background:#000;
font-size:27px;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:20px;
z-index:30;
padding:5px;
-moz-animation: fadeInRight 1 ease-in 1.3s backwards; -webkit-animation: fadeInRight 1s ease-in 1s backwards; animation: fadeInRight 1s ease-in 1s backwards;
opacity: 1;
}
.caption2 {
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFF;
background:#000;
font-size:22px;
position:absolute;
top:70px;
left:20px;
z-index:40;
padding:5px;
-moz-animation: fadeInLeft 1s  ease-in 1.5s backwards; -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 1s  ease-in 1.5s backwards; animation: fadeInLeft 1s  ease-in 1.5s backwards; 
    opacity:1;
}


.caption3 {
font-weight:bold;
color:#000;
background:#FFF;
border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
font-size:16px;
-moz-animation: fadeInLeft 1s ease-in 2s backwards; -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 1sease-in 2s backwards; animation: fadeInLeft 1 sease-in 2s backwards;
position:absolute;
bottom:80px;
right:80px;
z-index:50;
padding:5px;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Check out my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/defonic/npqB5/)

Comment: This is pretty interesting, looks like a great idea. But I can't figure out how to apply the animation to each slide. For me it only animates on page load, but not as each slide changes. Any tips??